# 'All week, all the time, all day' time markers

Tags: past-tense, present-tense, time-words, time-reference

I have locked up the internet to find an answer to my question by unfortunately I did not find a clear answer.

So my question is: **Are these time markers used for particular tenses (e.g: Past progressive, present perfect, etc.**) or it can be used in any tense? because most of the time I see these expressions used with progressive tenses only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are not restricted to progressive or perfect tenses.

"I work all day so I study law at night school." Present tense, habitual action.

"I shall work all day tomorrow, but I shall be free the day after." Simple future.

"I worked all day last Saturday." Simple past.

Comment: What about these two sentences: has it been raining all day? And has it rained all day? Which one is correct

Comment: Both are correct. There are cases where either will express the same thought.